# Split string and assign value in same array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like

```
array[0]["id_cart"]=> "1"["message"]=>"Product1, product2"
array[1]["id_cart"]=> "1"["message"]=>"Product1, product2"
```

what i want is to split `[0]["message"]` value and assign to 2nd array such as

```
array[0]["id_cart"]=> "1"["message"]=>"Product1"
array[1]["id_cart"]=> "1"["message"]=>"Product2"
```

thanks

Comment: what problem are you faced?

Comment: what had you tried so far?